# Is there a way to use Cucumber style integration testing for a multiplatform QT based application?

Tags: qt, continuous-integration, cucumber, integration-testing

We are building a qt application that is targeted to win32 and Linux. we would like to start integration testing with a cucumber style framework. We would like the test team to write the feature files and have the developers provide the actual execution steps. Are there any recommendations on how to do this? Either with FrogLogic Squish or QTTest?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://projects.forum.nokia.com/Testabilitydriver/wiki

*Testability Driver TDriver is a testing tool open sourced by Nokia. It will make test automation possible for Qt applications running on any platform that runs Qt. Platforms we have used include: Linux, Windows, Mac, Symbian, maemo and MeeGo?.*

It's a bit tricky to get up and running on win32 but it supports all the test frameworks from ruby: RUnit, FIT, RSpec and Cucumber!

Cheers